# Get values from multiple sql server table by one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables as following:
[image]

I want to select values of (userid from tbladmin) and (compname from tblcompany)

Basically userid is the username name and compname is the company name.
I want the name of the company/companies the user is affiliated to.

Hoping for answer.

Comment: Are you asking how to use `JOIN` syntax? I'm guessing you are very new to SQL? You might be better researching some tutorials online on how to use it. Learning about `JOIN` is a day 1 lesson. On a different note, storing a password in plain text in your database is a **big** "no no"! You should ideally be using a hash and salt.

Comment: Hey Larnu, yeah I am new to SQL and thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: This isn't specific to SQL Server, but it'll certainly teach you the basics: [W3Schools: SQL Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/). The syntax between different RDBMS does differ (SQL Server specfically uses what is known as T-SQL (Transact-SQL)). You can find the full documentation for SQL Server [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/sql-server-technical-documentation?view=sql-server-2017), however, it's not a tutorial, it's documentation; so it might not help someone who is brand new, but it's a very valuable resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join these tables:

```
select a.userid,c.compname
from tbladmin a
inner join userrights r on a.id=r.id
inner join tblcompany c on r.compid=c.compid
```